# Flutter url_launcher package breaking on Android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-packages

```
> Task :url_launcher_android:testDebugUnitTest FAILED

io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.MethodCallHandlerImplTest > stopListening_doesNothingWhenUnset FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at SandboxClassLoader.java:147
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at ClassReader.java:195

io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.MethodCallHandlerImplTest > stopListening_unregistersExistingChannel FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at SandboxClassLoader.java:147
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at ClassReader.java:195

io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.MethodCallHandlerImplTest > startListening_unregistersExistingChannel FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at SandboxClassLoader.java:147
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at ClassReader.java:195

io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.MethodCallHandlerImplTest > onMethodCall_closeWebView FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at SandboxClassLoader.java:147
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at ClassReader.java:195

io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.MethodCallHandlerImplTest > onMethodCall_canLaunchReturnsFalse FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at SandboxClassLoader.java:147
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at ClassReader.java:195

io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.MethodCallHandlerImplTest > onMethodCall_launchReturnsNoActivityError FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at SandboxClassLoader.java:147
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at ClassReader.java:195

io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.MethodCallHandlerImplTest > startListening_registersChannel FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at SandboxClassLoader.java:147
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at ClassReader.java:195

io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.MethodCallHandlerImplTest > onMethodCall_launchReturnsTrue FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at SandboxClassLoader.java:147
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at ClassReader.java:195

io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.MethodCallHandlerImplTest > onMethodCall_launchReturnsActivityNotFoundError FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at SandboxClassLoader.java:147
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at ClassReader.java:195

io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.MethodCallHandlerImplTest > onMethodCall_canLaunchReturnsTrue FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at SandboxClassLoader.java:147
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at ClassReader.java:195

io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivityTest > extractHeaders_returnsEmptyMapWhenHeadersBundleNull PASSED

11 tests completed, 10 failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

All the tests are failing for this plugin (url_launcher) and that's only for Android. I've come across this before with earlier version of Flutter / Android and the only way around it was to deactivate it completely.
The flutter doctor comes green out, no issues. I use gradle 8.1.1 and JDK 17 (although I'll be trying other versions too).